# Assigning variable to java list in play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to access a Java list from html code in play.
My list is returned by a public static method:

```
ComboboxOpts.getListOfValues()
```

I am using this method several times in my scala code want to assign it to some variable. Maybe something similar to this

```
@mylist = ComboboxOpts.getListOfValues()
```

So that I can use it like this

```
@for(i <- 0 to mylist.size -1){
    //Do stuff
}
```

rather than this

```
@for(i <- 0 to ComboboxOpts.getListOfValues.size -1){
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `defining()` to set new variables, such as:

```
@defining(getName() + " " + getType()) { text => 
  Hello @text!
}
```

However, for your case, you can just iterate over a list as follows:

```
@for(value <- ComboboxOpts.getListOfValues()) {
  <li>@value</li>
}
```

This will not call your function repeatedly, and is much more expressive. The Play documentation has several related examples: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates

If you absolutely need the index as well, try using Scala's `zipWithIndex()`.

Comment: My function call does a recursive call on a file directory to get all file names. And I want to avoid this recursive call multiple times since I loop through it multiple times in my code
Is there anyway to keep a reference to the list?

Comment: In that case, where you want to keep the list, use `defining()` as in my first example. It'll call it once, and let you use it many times.

Alternatively, you could add a getter to your controller that will call it once and cache the result.

Comment: @Omar Optionally you have also two other possibilities: 1) getListOfValues in the controller and pass it as a view's argument, 2) cache its result in memory for some short period ie. 60 seconds or shorter. You can of course mix both solutions for even better performance.

Comment: Thanks, the cache works great in combination of getListOfValues

Answer (score 0):

  **Application.java file**
1. public class Application extends Controller {
2. public static Result index() {
3. List myList = new ArrayList();
4. myList.add("one");
5. myList.add("two");
6. return ok(index.render(myList));
7. }
8. }
  **index.scala.html file**
9. @(myList: List[String])
10. @main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {
11. @for(item

    @item

    }

    }